# Ошибка: pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'Vol1rvag@% '@'ip' (using password: YES)") на Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, mysql, telebot, pymysql, pythonanywhere

Ребят, вынужден обратиться за помощью умных людей.

Я написал ТГ бота с БД MySQL и решил залить на хостинг Pythonanywhere.
База данных изначально не хранит никаких значений, поэтому я решил создать её заново на сервере.

Значения в файле config в десктопе:

```
MySQL = ['localhost', 'user', 'password', 'support_db']
```

Значения на сервере:

```
MySQL = ['Vol1rvag.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com', 'Vol1rvag', 'v8Q04JfB73FpH7y', 'support_db']
```

Однако при любой команде в консоле, вылезат данная ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На форумах люди пишут, что нужно изменить пароль через команду:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

На локальной версии это работает, но тут всегда вылезает ошибка:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Я только учусь и набираюсь опыта самостоятельными мини-проектами, если кто сталкивался с таким же, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Всем заранее **ОГРОМНОЕ** спасибо!

p.s. Использую бесплатный тариф на Pythonanywhere

Comment: У Вас в username ошибка - пробел там закрался. Внизу скриншота смотрите внимательно

Comment: 'Vol1rvag@% ' <- и не только пробел

Comment: А в MySQL = [..., 'Vol1rvag' ...]. Какое имя верное?

Comment: @Виктор Если ввести в консоли mysql  "show grants", то он выдает имя вот такое: Vol1rvag@%, логин на сайте такой же без символов( 

Пробел поправил, ошибка не ушла((

Comment: @Виктор Мне начинает казаться, что я задумал невозможное и в бесплатной версии на хостинге это все развернуть нельзя, а только на vps сервере

Comment: Вы посмотрите, что Ваш тариф позволяет. Там должно быть.